# Clarify or disambiguate notation from textbook

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm reading Murphy's Machine Learning: A probabilistic perspective. Exercise 2.9 asks:

## Exercise 2.9

Conditional independence

Are the following properties true? Prove or disprove. Note that we are not restricting attention to distributions that can be represented by a graphical model.

1. True or false?
   $$
   (X \perp W \mid Z, Y)\wedge (X \perp Y \mid Z) \implies (X \perp Y, W \mid Z)
   $$

where $(A \perp B \mid C)$ means 
$$
p(A, B \mid C) = p(A \mid C) p(B \mid C)
$$

---

I need clarification on how to parse
$$
(X \perp Y, W \mid Z)
$$

Does this mean that
$$
p(X, Y, W \mid Z) = p(X \mid Z)p(Y, W \mid Z)
$$